# How to concatenate two tensors horizontally in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have 2 tensors of shape `(100, 4)` and `(100, 2)`. 
I would like to perform a concatenation operation, in TensorFlow, similar to `np.hstack`, in NumPy, so that the output would be of shape `(100, 6)`. Is there a TensorFlow function to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `tf.concat` for this purpose as follows:

```
sess=tf.Session()
t1 = [[1, 2], [4, 5]]
t2 = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
res=tf.concat(concat_dim=1,values=[t1, t2])
print(res.eval(session=sess))
```

This prints

```
[[ 1  2  7  8  9]
 [ 4  5 10 11 12]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate tensors without using tf.concat()?

Comment: @Pototo One can use `tf.stack()` in some cases.

Comment: Batch size is considered as first dimension? Also looks like API is changed https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat

Comment: It's now (I'm using TF version 1.6.0):  `axis=1` , _not_ `concat_dim=1`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above code, I got some error. The following code runs fine with tf 1.15 version:

```
x = tf.constant( [[1, 2,4],[7,8,12]])
```

`y = tf.constant([[88],[99]])`

```
res=tf.concat([x, y],1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I try to concatenate two image Tensors with Keras.
[Tensor type and shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1CpC.png)
Both are identical but it says that Layer concatenate_X (The Number X changes)was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
i try to concatenate them like this:

```
X=concatenate([X1,X2],axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way of doing it in PyTorch. Suppose t1 is your 100x4 tensor and t2 is 100x2 tensor. You can do something like:

```
result= torch.concat((t1,t2), axis=1)
```

The result is a 100x6 tensor.

Comment: This solution works for PyTorch. OP is asking for a solution in TensorFlow.

Comment: Oh Alright, thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my answer.